# Git show --name-status --format=oneline, showing only revised file instead of original and revised

Tags: git

I made a commit, and I'm almost sure I renamed the file from `cortex-rules.yaml` to `cortex-rule.yaml`.
My expectation is that I would get the original and revised filenamebut instead I get :

```
> git show --name-status --format=full 9070d7d70dfbef77599cdada8c2ce42832654e36
commit 9070d7d70dfbef77599cdada8c2ce42832654e36 (origin/development)
Merge: 4a71760 c14516d
Author: 
Commit: 

edit 28
RR rules/applications/nap-tom/cortex-rule.yaml
```

I looked at the documentation and I know that after R there should be a score (eg. R087) but this time it's a letter and not sure what it means. Does anyone know what it means a commit status of `RR` and how can I get the original file and revision file name?

Comment: This is a merge commit, and the file seems to have been renamed on both parents.

Comment: Also, "I looked at the documentation and I know that after R there should be a score" seems strange to me. `--name-status` gives letter codes (two letters), take a look [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format).

Comment: aplogies, still quite new to git documentation. I tried to replicate what happened but unsuccessfully. I have 2 branches main and dev, made the same rename on both, committed and then merger but I get 
git show --name-status --format=oneline <hash>
<hash> ( HEAD -> dev, origin/main, main) Merge pull request #1 from ../dev
without any rename change in the commit

Comment: R-and-score happens with an extended `git diff` but to get a single score you need to diff against a single parent. For this particular case, for instance, you could run `git diff 4a71760 9070d7d` to compare the first parent against the commit, or `git diff c14516d 9070d7d` to compare the second parent against the commit.

Comment: To reproduce this kind of RR status, run a merge with `--no-commit` (or one that has a conflict so that you get the implied `--no-commit` effect), then rename a file that has some name `foo` in both parents to some new name `bar` in the merge, and commit the result. But note that in this particular case, you have the merge commit's full hash ID (`9070d7d70dfbef77599cdada8c2ce42832654e36`): that hash ID means *that* commit, and only that commit, ever. You don't need to reproduce the effect, you can just use any repository that has *that* commit.